# How can I pull annotations from a data set in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a bunch of Tableau sheets showing sales over the year by date. I'd like to add some annotations, but I'd like to add them to all sheets by date. So ideally, I'd have a data set like this:

```
date       | annotation
2019-01-01 | Started the year off strong
2019-02-15 | Here's where we did something great
2019-04-22 | Here's where our systems completely crashed
2019-06-19 | Here's where we did our big summer promotion
```

Then I'd like to just apply this to all my sales charts. So that it looks like this:

[image: Chart with annotations]

I know I can just right-click and add an annotation. However, I want to be able to overlay these events on ANY chart I create with a date x-axis.

The real problem is that I create tons of charts showing sales. But I always have to annotate a bunch of events over and over again. I'd like to just create the list of events and overlay them on any chart. How would I do that?